# Passing Boolean value to Angular Dialog results in error but works

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I have the weird problem, that when I try to pass a boolean value to a dialog component, the compiler gives me an error, stating that the property doesn't exist on the DialogData type. However, the actual performance off my app is correct, suggesting that it does indeed work. How can I resolve this error?

Here is my code:

Component.ts:

```
openDialog(questionnaire: Questionnaire): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample, {
    width: '450px',
    data: {openFormat: questionnaire.openFormat,
         question: questionnaire.questions[this.index].phrase}
  })
}
```

The HTML

```
    <div class="container" *ngIf="!data.openFormat">
      <p>{{data.question}}</p>
      <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container" *ngIf="data.openFormat">
        <p>{{data.question}}</p>
    </div>
```

The button gets displayed, as expected, only when data.openFormat is false.

[image: Error code]

Greetings :)

Comment: Share the error screenshot

Comment: What do you expect? The list of actions is only shown when `!data.openFormat` resolves to `true` as you've nested the actions inside of the `div.container` element which has an `*ngIf` conditional.

Comment: Like I said, everything works fine BUT the compiler throws an error. This is it: https://imgur.com/a/lddjMW9

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, sorry.

I kinda copied the example from the stackblitz in the dialog doc and had an interface sitting in the top like:

```
export interface DialogData {
    data: string
}
```

Now, obviously, I just had to add a property with openFormat to that interface and the error is gone.

Thanks for your attention guys.